# Indexing with Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, indexing

I was working with the code below and having issues compiling this. What i am trying to achieve is an indexed word usages such that for each word it cites the location the number in the file, for each file. So lets say if we have "boy" in abc.txt, we get something like

boy /usr/abc.txt: 1 3

Meaning boy is first and 3rd word in the file

I am using this code below, and i see  2 errors while compiling. One is cannot find the GenericOptionsParser and the other is can't find the filename. I tried to modify the generic WordCount code to this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordIndex {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {



      //context.getInputSplit();
      //Path filePath = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath();
      //String filename = ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();

      String line = value.toString();
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
      //StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {


      String fileName = ((org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
        word.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]+","") +" "+ filename); // get rid of special char
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
      System.exit(2);

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(DocWordIndex.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: please add stacktraces of errors to your question

Comment: WordIndex.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        word.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]+","") +" "+ filename); // get rid of special char
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable filename
  location: class TokenizerMapper
DocWordIndex.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
                             ^
  symbol:   class GenericOptionsParser
  location: class DocWordIndex
2 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code AS-IS and was able to compile after making 3 modifications:

1. In the following statement, change `filename` to `fileName` ('N' capital in `fileName`)

   Change:

   ```
   word.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]+","") +" "+ filename);
   ```

   To:

   ```
   word.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]+","") +" "+ fileName);
   ```
2. Imported package `GenericOptionsParser`:

   Add following import:

   ```
   import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
   ```
3. `job.setJarByClass()` was wrong. It was set to `DocWordIndex.class` instead of `WordIndex.class`.

   Change:

   ```
   job.setJarByClass(DocWordIndex.class);
   ```

   To:

   ```
   job.setJarByClass(WordIndex.class);
   ```

This compiled the code for me.

My maven dependencies are (I am using Hadoop 2.7.0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Manjunath!! That compiled. I am totally new to Hadoop, and was trying to do all that from the Terminal. Let me try that against a test file and see if i can get indexes of words from it.